# Accessing class type

Tags: xtend

I'm trying to convert following java snippet to Xtend, but i couldn't able to do it. I'm not able to access static property 'class'.

```
public class SyncService{
  private static final String LOGT = SyncService.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

I tried following methods,

```
class SyncService {
    val LOGT = SyncService.class.getSimpleName();
}
class SyncService {
    val LOGT = SyncService::class.getSimpleName();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#typeLiteral) it's

```
SyncService.simpleName
```

or with the legacy syntax:

```
typeof(SyncService).simpleName
```

Comment: Where is that in the documentation? I was going to edit your answer to add a link, but all I could find was the "[Accessing static members differs from Java](http://jnario.org/org/jnario/jnario/documentation/20FactsAboutXtendSpec.html)" section in an FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's documented in the literals section of the reference docs: http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#Xtend_Expressions_Literals

Comment: New link: https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#type-literal